# Como eu sei se um Shader está funcionando?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

Meu código está certo? Estou usando Python e Pyglet, como eu sei se o shader está rodando, por que eu peguei o código do shader na internet:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
import pyshaders as ps

t = pyglet.window.Window()

v = """
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

out vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
"""

f = """
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}
"""

shader = ps.from_string(v,f)

@t.event
def on_draw():
    glClearColor(1,0,0,1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    shader.use()
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glColor3f(1,1,1)
    glVertex2f(10,10)
    glVertex2f(10,50)
    glVertex2f(60,70)
    glEnd()

def SRO(dt):
    on_draw()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(SRO, 1/60)

pyglet.app.run()
```

E sim eu sei OpenGL mas sou um iniciante em GLSL, já testei outros códigos do shader na internet mas todos sempre dão a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As coordenadas estão demasiado altas. Depois de testar aparece um triângulo da cor definida.

```
shader = ps.from_string(v,f)
shader.use()

@t.event
def on_draw():
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.95)
    glVertex2f(0.95, -0.95)
    glVertex2f(-0.95, -0.95)
    glEnd()
```

Comment: Por que houve essa mudança das dimensões em que eu podia desenhar? Antes do shader elas funcionavam

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o GLSL linter que faz a verificação de sintaxe dos seus arquivos de shaders, existe extensões para ele em alguns editores de texto (eu uso no vscode), no seu caso você precisa extrair a string do shader em um novo arquivo e usar a lib de arquivos do python para fazer a leitura dos arquivos shaders, aparentemente seus shaders estão corretos.

O OpenGL trabalha com um negócio chamado "Normalized Device Coordinates", em resumo, você precisa passar as coordenadas com valores entre -1.0 em cada um dos 3 eixos. Para que você informe uma coordenada de um mundo personalizado você deve utilizar as matrizes MVP (model, view, projection).

Normalized Device Coordinates
https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

Coordinate Systems
https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems